# Liquibase Context with SQL and MVN

Tags: maven, liquibase

I have an MVN project for managing DB migration using Liquibase 3.1.1

I have a properties file containing the contexts I would like to run

```
contexts=development
```

which is being loaded as I see the following in output

```
[INFO]     context(s): development
```

I have a databaseChangeLog something like the following

```
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">

    <include file="changesets/api/pmck/pmck-1.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
    <include file="changesets/api/pmck/pmck-2.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

file pmck-1.sql which I want to run when not in dev contexts:

```
-- liquibase formatted sql
-- changeset pmck:pmck-1.sql context=!development failOnError:true

create table PMCK_TEST_PRODUCTION_ONLY_TABLE(
  ID CHAR(128) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO PMCK_TEST_PRODUCTION_ONLY_TABLE
(ID)
VALUES(uuid()),
  (uuid());
```

and a second sql I want to always run regardless of contexts:

```
-- liquibase formatted sql
-- changeset pmck:pmck-2.sql failOnError:true

create table PMCK_TEST_TABLE(
  ID CHAR(128) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO PMCK_TEST_TABLE
(ID)
VALUES(uuid()),
  (uuid());
```

I am finding that both are being run when I run `mvn install`, regardless of context value. How can I get only one to run? Am I missing something

Comment: Maybe you need to write a colon not equals char, like `context:` not `context=`

Comment: @Jens #facepalm thank you! that worked.

Comment: You're welcome!